# bootstrap 3 datetimepicker start date 2 weeks ahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to start my datetimepicker 2weeks ahead.... here's my code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There are a few third-party libs out there with this name: [1](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), [2](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) best to be clear which one your using.

Comment: By start do you mean have it set to select a date 2 weeks out? Or have it set to have a minimum selectable date that is 2 weeks out?

Comment: The date  today + 2weeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/5532/

```js
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment().add('days', 14)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've used moment to add 14days.

You can add weeks as well instead of days

```js
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  defaultDate: moment().add('weeks', 2)
});
```

For disabling the past dates

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
   minDate: moment().add('days', 14)
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Please refer to jsFiddle as the code is not working in stackoverflow because of library link.

Comment: @Neilzxc. You need to follow jsfiddle. In stackoverflow it's not working.

Comment: Oh thanks! How about to disable the past days so that user cant click past days?

Comment: @Neilzxc Use below code `$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().add('days', 14)
});`

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code....

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: '+7d'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That is only 7 days ahead he said 2 weeks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you're using this library: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

```
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'years',
    defaultDate: formatDate(getDateTwoWeeksFromNow())
  });
});

function getDateTwoWeeksFromNow() {
  new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
}

function formatDate(date) {
  return [date.getDate(), date.getMonth(),date.getFullYear()].join('/')
}
```

Comment: If your using eonasdan's why are you using moment.js?

Comment: Where am I using momentjs?

Comment: Sorry typo you are NOT, I was asking why were your not using it. Given it is much easier to define dates, it is a required library for the date picker, and the date picker uses it internally for native dates.